# group_concat returns null, if another column added

Tags: mysql, bigdata

I have the following code

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('{"id"', id, ','),
    CONCAT('"COL1"', col1, ','),
    CONCAT('"col2"', col2, ','),
    CONCAT('"col3"', col3, ','),
    CONCAT('"col4"', col4, '}')
    SEPERATOR '\n')
  AS json from tableX
```

The whole group_concat returns null. If I removed one concat (at random) it works.

The table contains about 15 million rows. 
I have set

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 188446744073709551615;
```

Any ideas why it return null?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, handling any null values and seeing if your output is indeed exceeding the length threshold:

```
  select json, length(json) from (
  SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('{"id"', coalesce(id, '""'), ','),
    CONCAT('"COL1"', coalesce(col1, '""'), ','),
    CONCAT('"col2"', coalesce(col2, '""'), ','),
    CONCAT('"col3"', coalesce(col3, '""'), ','),
    CONCAT('"col4"', coalesce(col4, '""'), '}')
    SEPARATOR '\n')
  AS json from tableX
  ) x
  -- limit 200000
```

If the group_concat function lets NULL values override everything else (I'm not sure about that), then you have it catered for.

**UPDATE**: `SEPERATOR` was a typo - it should be `SEPARATOR`.

Comment: add quote (`""`) if value empty otherwise `[12,,,]` is invalid json

Comment: @Dan: do you get a length output at all? Can you try including the `limit` term and increase until you encounter the problem?

Comment: Still just returns null. The whole statement. Even though I add limit it returns null... still, if I remove one CONCAT it works..

Comment: @Dan: are you using SEPARATOR (one "e")? I tried it out on my database and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @davek, yeah SEPARATOR